# What are my options for HTML templating when not using a web server?

Tags: html, templates, template-engine, no-framework

**Rules**

1. One option per answer
2. List language constraints
3. A minimum of one pro and one con
4. At least one URL resource.

If your feeling generous include a description or your own experience with it.

Comment: Almost exactly the same as your options when you are using a web server.

Comment: Well I can only answer 4 out of 5. I guess I'm not qualified to answer your question.

Comment: @Byran: Feeling pedantic I see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XSLT**

Language Agnostic

**Pro:**

- Extremely versatile
- Language Agnostic

**Cons:**

- Learning curve
- Variation across implementations
- XML syntax can be verbose

[W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)

[.NET XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/)

Language: Python 2.4+

Pro: It's flexible

Con: You need a C compiler for debugging

It's a generic templating engine written in Python. It's often used as an alternative to the Django templating engine by people who don't like the restrictive nature of the Django templating engine.

Answer (score 1):

[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)

Language: Java

Pro: It's flexible

Con: Not as popular as it once was.

This is another generic templating engine, this one written in Java. At one time, it was a popular alternative to JSP, although it has fallen off a bit since then.

Answer (score 0):

Stringtemplate can be used as a generic code emitter. Written in Java

Answer (score 0):

[DOM Style APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772065) + [CSS Generated Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772051)

**PROS**

- No extra markup
- Unicode support

**CONS**

- Trial and Error
- No documentation

**References**

- [CSSplay - Borders, Shadows and Radial Gradients](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-borders-shadows-gradients.html)
- [CSS3 Photo-Info version 2](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-photo-info.html)
- [oneBox](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/oneBox.html)
- ['Content:' - CSSplay - Gallery 100](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/content100.html)
- [CSS play - CSS only 'loading' animation with no extra markup](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-loading-animation.html)
- [CSS Tree Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432153/create-a-tree-structure/20410395#20410395)
- [CSS Venn Diagram](http://css.dzone.com/articles/venn-diagram-entirely-css)