# Create a tree structure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, visualization, hierarchical-data

I am working on an asp .net project. In my aspx page i have a gridview which has 3 columns("element","Target","Parent"). On the client side i want to build a tree structure using the data in the gridview and then build a tree with figures. I found information and modules about how to build the figure but i want some advice on how to make the structure. Are there any ready javascript algorithms to do this?. Thx in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: Please post some sample data from the gridview

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS tree, such as the following:

- [CSS Tree](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/)
- [CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)

Use the `:checked` pseudo class to style checkboxes as presentational elements to emulate state, such as:

```
 .folder input[type='checkbox']:checked { display: block; }
 .folder input[type='checkbox'] { display: inline; }
```

Combine that with `<label>` elements as proxies to hide/show on demand, and nested `<blockquote>` elements as hierarchy.

**References**

- [CSS3 Selectors: :checked pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked)
- [CSS Selectors: The UI element states pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#The_UI_element_states_pseudo-classes)